# default date value prior to 1970, Invalid default value for

Tags: mysql, date

i keep getting this error when trying to set up a default value for a date field:
Invalid default value for 'created'

```
ALTER TABLE artwork CHANGE COLUMN created created TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '1954-09-18 00:00:00' AFTER updated;
```

I've tried every year and i notice that prior to 1970, mysql rejects the date. I mean it's not a big problem, i really don't need the default date to be 1954, if i want that date it is mostly for symbolic reasons.

Assuming that there is no direct solution for my issue, then my question is: why is it that mysql rejects default dates prior to 1970 ?

Thanks

Comment: The minimum timestamp value is 1970-01-01 00:00:01. It also depends on your mysql timezone, so it may shift a few hours.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with mysql, but Unix timestamps (which are widely used) are a count of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 GMT.  If mysql uses that format internally, it probably doesn't like a timestamp with a negative value.

**EDIT:**

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-type-overview.html :

> TIMESTAMP
>
> A timestamp. The range is '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-19
>   03:14:07' UTC. TIMESTAMP values are stored as the number of seconds
>   since the epoch ('1970-01-01 00:00:00' UTC). A TIMESTAMP cannot
>   represent the value '1970-01-01 00:00:00' because that is equivalent
>   to 0 seconds from the epoch and the value 0 is reserved for
>   representing '0000-00-00 00:00:00', the “zero” TIMESTAMP value.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL's TIMESTAMP type is a counter representing [Unix time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). That's the number of seconds since the start of January 1, 1970. Why it is signed (maximum date is in 2038 -- half the time that would would be allowable if it were unsigned) and doesn't allow dates outside the 1970-2038 range is beyond me. See also the [MySQL documentation on this column type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html).

The DATETIME column type uses twice the space (8 bytes), but the supported range there is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to '9999-12-31 23:59:59'.

Comment: Presumably it's 32 bits and signed for compatibility with most Unix-like systems.  Making it unsigned rather than signed would extend the upper bound to early 2106, but at the expense of not being able to represent times before 1970.  Many systems already use 64-bit time_t; I expect that before 2038 rolls around, most or all of them will.  (64 bits, even signed, will take us to the year 292271025015.)

Comment: That's the odd thing... it DOESN'T represent time before 1970 even though it has the bit reserved.

Comment: But Unix systems typically are able to represent times before 1970.  Even if MySQL doesn't use negative `time_t` values for whatever reason, it still makes sense to maintain consistency.